# youtube-iframe-api remove suggestion thumbnails at bottom of video

Tags: youtube, youtube-iframe-api

Could somebody tell me how to remove [youtube suggestion thumbnails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLIpp.png) on embedded video.

I am using iframe api. It feel like it should be easy. But i just can't find anything on google on how to do it.

`tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
function initPLayer(playerDivId){
  return new YT.Player(playerDivId, {
    height: '390',
    width: '640',
    videoId: '4EDMR75lrKY',
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady1,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChangePlayer1
    }
  });
}`

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

I knew it was obvious :P.

There is thing called [player parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?playerVersion=HTML5).
Rel:
This parameter indicates whether the player should show related videos when playback of the initial video ends. Supported values are 0 and 1. The default value is 1.