# Youtube player is not show when you go next page and come back again : ionic

Tags: angular, youtube-api, ionic3

I am using https://github.com/morganster/ionic-youtube-ng2 library to implement youtube player in ionic 3. 
Its working fine when we open home page(I am using player on homepage only), than go to next page using `navCtrl.push`. and come back to home page using back button.

But when i am going to next page using `navCtrl.setRoot` and come back from menus(drawer menu) than home page doe not have YouTube player, div is empty that time.

I got error on `this.youtube.player.destroy();`
I changed this to `this.youtube.destroy();` still doesn't work when i come back to home page.

I have added extra code on `https://github.com/morganster/ionic-youtube-ng2/blob/master/src/pages/home/home.ts` at last wih NavController Module

```
gototTest(){
   this.navCtrl.setRoot(TestPage);
}
```

home.html

```
<button (click)="gotoTest()">Go to Test Page</button>
```

And created one TestPage in page folder with function

```
 gototHome(){
   this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
}
```

test.html

```
<button (click)="gotoHome()">Go to Home Page</button>
```

I am going to test page using button click and come back to home page by click on gotoHome() button. Now that time, youtube player div is empty. Nothing is playing, no youtube iframe.

Comment: please consider providing us some code to be able to help you.

Comment: Hi, I have edited my code. I am using complete repository https://github.com/morganster/ionic-youtube-ng2

Comment: It seems you are trying to do a navigation here. Why won't you use the [Angular router](https://angular.io/guide/router) and components for that? Rendering is not recommended "by hand" I think.

Answer (score 0):

The code is adapted for a single page app. Here's what you can do. (PS: the player also runs in a page stack but not after setRoot)

- Cut the code `var tag` ... `firstScriptTag);` from app.components.ts and paste it into yourPage.ts just below the constructor, a new function, `ionViewWillEnter()`:

  ```
  ionViewWillEnter(){
      let tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      let firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
      this.ytPlayer.setupPlayer();
  }
  ```

  Note also the changes in `this.player.setupPlayer()`.
  And thats all.

Here is the [explanation on another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46125780/5525657)